# how to make my @ request param variable as a public variable in controller Layer in java

Tags: java, spring

I have created one ajax call in UI. Through the ajax call, I am sending one String variable as a request param. Now i want to access this request param variable in another method which is in the same class. How to make my request param variable as a public variable.

This is the code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cDetails").change(function() {
            var value1 = $('#cDetails:selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'envi',
                data : {
                    cname : value1
                },
                success : function(result) {

               }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller Layer.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(@RequestParam String cname) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("cname"+cname);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());
    List<Environments>  environmentnamesList= loginDelegate.getEnvironments(cname);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println("gson"+gson);
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
    System.out.println("jsonString"+jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}
```

In this same clas, I want to access this cname varible.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retri", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) throws Exception{

    system.out.println("cname " + cname);
}
```

Can any one suggest me.

Comment: I cant understand the scenario completely but wont assigning cname to a class variable solve your issue ?

Comment: You can set cname in coockie and receive the same in next call.

Comment: u will have to resend `cname` to `/retri` ajax call

Comment: i am not making ajax call for second reqest mapping.using action i am making a call.like  
<form:form method="get" commandName="frmSample" action="retri" modelAttribute="customer">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two requests are made by the same client in the same session you can add the cname value to the Session.

```
getEnvironmentNames(@RequestParam String cname, HttpServletRequest rq){
...
 rq.getSession().setAttribute("cname", cname);
...
}
```

and then in test

```
test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) throws Exception{

    system.out.println("cname " + request.getSession().getAttribute("cname"));
}
```

If it is not the case, you need to store the value of cname in a repository like a Database.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a variable in class and set it to the value when you pass it the first time. And you can re-use it in any method in the controller.

private String var;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envi", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(@RequestParam String cname)      throws SQLException {  
    System.out.println("cname"+cname);  
    var=cname;  
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();  
    modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());  
    List<Environments>   
    environmentnamesList=loginDelegate.getEnvironments(cname);  
    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    System.out.println("gson"+gson);  
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);  
    System.out.println("jsonString"+jsonString);  
    return jsonString;
```

}

and in here

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retri", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse      response,   
    @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) throws Exception{  

    system.out.println("cname" + **var**);
```

}

Comment: The controller bean is a singleton. Its methods are accessed concurrently by multiple requests, so they must either be stateless or have proper synchronization on the shared state. Using a controller's `String` field is not thread-safe.

Comment: Totally forgot about that my bad.